# htaccess rewrite for default.asp to index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Can you please show me how to create rewrite rule in htaccess to convert from default.asp to index.php with the same directory?

Here is what I have so far

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ ^(.*)\index.php$ [R,L,NC]
```

But it is not working. I like to be able to convert from defaut.asp to index.php regardless of the URL structure.

For example, if https://myownsite.com/about/that/default.asp then it will become https://myownsite.com/about/that/index.php

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)default\.asp$
RewriteRule ^ /%1index.php [R=301,L]
```